# Как сделать чтобы ссылки подсвечивались если не происходит ни каких действий?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мини игра по поиску предметов, при нажатии на искомый предмет он исчезает "display: none". Как сделать чтобы первый по списку предмет подсвечиваля если пользователь не может их найти в течении 5сек. Использую только JavaScript без JQuery. [GitHub](https://github.com/Olegm23/minigame)

```js
function impossibru() {
  if (document.getElementById('apple').style.display === 'none' && document.getElementById('shoe').style.display === 'none' && document.getElementById('book').style.display === 'none' && document.getElementById('purse').style.display === 'none') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('begin').style.display = 'none';
    }, 1000)
  }
}
document.getElementById('ap').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('apple').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('one').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
  impossibru();
};
document.getElementById('sh').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('shoe').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('two').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
  impossibru();
};
document.getElementById('bk').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('book').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('three').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
  impossibru();
};
document.getElementById('pr').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('purse').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('for').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
  impossibru();
};
impossibru();
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="begin" class="beginer"> <img class="bg" src="img/bg_ho.png" alt="bg">
      <div class="tutorial1"><img class="tutorial" src="img/Tutorial1.png" alt="tutorial">
        <p class="pulsate">Find all the
          <br>hidden objects!</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#one" id="ap"> <img class="apple" id="apple" src="img/apple.png" alt="apple"></a>
      <a href="#two" id="sh"> <img class="shoe" id="shoe" src="img/shoe.png" alt="shoes"> </a>
      <a href="#three" id="bk"> <img class="book" id="book" src="img/book.png" alt="book"> </a>
      <a href="#for" id="pr"> <img class="purse" id="purse" src="img/purse.png" alt="apple"> </a>
      <div class="bottom"><img class="bottom" src="img/ho_gui.png" alt="bottom">
        <div class="text">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h1 id="one">Apple</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1 id="two">Shoe</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1 id="three">Book</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1 id="for">Purse</h1>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fs" class="finish"> <img class="blur" src="img/bg_blur.png" alt="bg">
      <div class="lg"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="no logo"></div>
      <button class="button" type="button"> <a href="#">Play Free</a> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Каких? "ни каких"

Comment: проблема с подсвечиванием или с ожиданием 5 секунд?

Comment: @Igor пользователь не кликает.

Comment: @Grundy Проблема с подсвечиванием через 5 секунд элементов по поряду, если элемент еще не скрыт